# MySQL: Failed to add the foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I have two table, `clinics` and `consultations`. 
Each consultation record to belong to one clinic, so I thought I would set `clinic_name` as foreign key referencing the `clinic_name` in the `clinics` table. But it throw an error:

```
code: 'ER_FK_NO_INDEX_PARENT',
errno: 1822, sqlMessage: "Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'consultations_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'clinics'",
```

**clinics table:**

```
const sql_createclinics =
  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clinics(" +
  "id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
  "email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, " +
  "password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, " +
  "clinic_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, " +
  "phone_num VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, " +
  "address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, " +
  "PRIMARY KEY (id))";
```

**consultations table:**

```
const sql_createconsult =
  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS consultations(" +
  "id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
  "clinic_name VARCHAR(255), " +
  "doctor_name VARCHAR(255), " +
  "patient_name VARCHAR(255), " +
  "diagnosis VARCHAR(255), " +
  "medication VARCHAR(255), " +
  "consultation_fee FLOAT, " +
  "datetime DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " +
  "PRIMARY KEY (id)," +
  "FOREIGN KEY (clinic_name) REFERENCES clinics(clinic_name))";
```

Comment: just to clarify -- I just add `CONSTRAINT FK_clinicname` before the `FOREIGN KEY` part?

Comment: `clinic_name` is not a primary key in clinics table

Comment: should i do `FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES clinics(id)` in consultations?

Comment: yes, that will do. but you don't need to declare ID  as Auto Increment column in `consultations` table

Comment: @SoumendraMishra makes sense. thanks!

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES clinics(id)`: this is not correct. If you want to link using id you should replace clinic_name by clinic_id and add `FOREIGN KEY (clinic_id) REFERENCES clinics(id)`

Comment: okay. that makes sense too. thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key should refer to a single record in another table.
With your schema definition you have no guarantee the clinic_name is unique. If `clinics.clinic_name` is unique force it in your database by creating a unique index for it. Otherwise do not use clinic_name as foreign key but put clinics id in consulations and create a foreign key constraint with id.

With clinic_id as relation:

```
const sql_createconsult =
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS consultations(" +
"id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
"clinic_id INT, " +
"doctor_name VARCHAR(255), " +
"patient_name VARCHAR(255), " +
"diagnosis VARCHAR(255), " +
"medication VARCHAR(255), " +
"consultation_fee FLOAT, " +
"datetime DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " +
"PRIMARY KEY (id)," +
"FOREIGN KEY (clinic_id) REFERENCES clinics(clinic_id))";
```

Comment: `clinic_id` is type INT and `clinic_name` is VARCHAR(255)

Comment: `clinic_id` column is not exists in `clinics` table

Comment: have you read my answer. it is better to reference the real primary key in a relationship. When tomorrow the name of the clinic changes, you will have to update all consultations related to this clinic. But if you want to stick to the clinic_name, you will have to make it unique by adding a unique constraint/index.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS consultations( 
  id INT,  
  clinic_name VARCHAR(255),  
  doctor_name VARCHAR(255),  
  patient_name VARCHAR(255),  
  diagnosis VARCHAR(255),  
  medication VARCHAR(255),  
  consultation_fee FLOAT,  
  datetime DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES clinics(id));
```